# Emulate PC Screens in Program-Windows/Apps?

Tags: windows, windows-10, screen, monitor, multiple-monitors

For a long time, i had a 3 screen setup with 3 similar screens (24", 16:10, 1920x1200), but i recently upgraded the center monitor to a newer model (23,8", 16:9,2560x1440)

in the past, i was able to simulate a super-wide-screen with NVIDIA Surround, telling the PC that my 3 24" are in fact one screen with 5760x1200. i was not really happy with this rather clunky solution, but since my center screen is now different, even this procedure doesn't work anymore.

i'm looking for a way to kind of unlink screens in windows from the hardware, i want to separate the physical abilities of my hardware from what i tell my software to do, meaning: i'm looking for a way where i can tell my PC "this is a 4k screen" when it actually just is a window that i resize, position, scale and display at my own will.

for example, when i work in Premiere Pro and try to use all my screens, i am often stuck with something like this:

https://imgur.com/a/g9KQV2v

what i'm looking for is a way that lets me precisely say "i want × physical pixels on my screen to emulate and display × pixels of screen". To pick up the previous example in the screenshot, i want to display Premiere Pro like this:

https://imgur.com/a/gafdEad

(yes, i can drag and drop the single components in this particular application, thats not the point^^)

i know that there are physical limitations and issues that will arise, but these are negligible for my use-cases - sometimes its better to have more screen space with slightly blurry fonts than to have less screen space with crisp fonts.

Please, if anybody has any tips or ideas on how to achieve something like this, let me know - i am currently considering replacing my center-screen with the older screen just to make NVIDIA Surround work again, but to be honest -   should be able to provide a better solution for this..

Any Tips or infos are highly appreciated!

*Edit: reading this again, i am aware that it might be not completely clear what the issue at hand is - if anybody can help with a better way to desribe this, it would be highly appreciated, since english isn't my native language*

Comment: you could create a virtual secondary screen with this https://www.amyuni.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3030 and use OBS to display that virtual screen on your physical screen, but that would not solve the issue of the different display sizes when you stretch your workspace over multiple screens with different DPI. heres a paste of a post describing simulating higher resolutions on small screens: https://pastebin.com/iCmJmRq7